# 'loop in gettable' Lua error when accessing an 'attribute' of a Lua table

Tags: lua

I have a Lua table representing a graph which contains nodes, which in turn can contain a "hypergraphnode" which can be recursively looped into itself. E.g. a hypergraphnode contains a Lua table hypergraphnode which is the same hypergraphnode. This causes an endless loop which I want to get rid of by deleting said hypergraphnodes. Now I wrote this code, where data can be any kind of Lua table, but will be primarily a Lua table representing a node:

```
local function fixInfiniteRecursion(data)
    if type(data) == 'table' then
        if data['hypergraphnode'] ~= nil then
            data.hypergraphnode = nil
        end
    end
end
```

Which should do the trick, but I get an error saying

> lua: src/serializer/serializer.lua:40: loop in gettable

But I do not understand what the problem is. The error points to line `if data['hypergraphnode'] ~= nil then`.

Comment: Do you have `__index` metamethod defined for `data`?

Comment: Yes, I do, it specifies the type of the 'object'.
    __index = {
         _type = 'pGraphHandler'
      }

Comment: This error message means you have more than 100 nested indexing using `__index` or `__newindex` metamethods.